# stderr not redirected to stdout

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I run a [TACACS+ server](http://www.pro-bono-publico.de/projects/tac_plus.html) which sends debug information to `stderr`. As I would like to grep specific data from this debug information, I redirected `stderr` to `stdout`: `tac_plus -f /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg 2>&1`. However, looks like it actually did not go to `stdout`, because if I execute `tac_plus -f /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg 2>&1 | cat`, then I see no output at all. On the other hand, `( echo blah >&2 ) 2>&1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'` works as expected:

```
$ ( echo blah >&2 ) 2>&1 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
BLAH
$
```

Could somebody explain this behavior? Shell is bash version 4.2.37.

Comment: are you sure tac_plus sends output to stderr? May be there is no output sent to stderr?

Comment: the output may be buffered to a pipe. Try prefixing the tac_plus command with `stdbuf -oL -eL`.

Comment: @HameedullahKhan Yes, because if I do `tac_plus -f /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg 2>/dev/null`, then there is no output. On the other hand, in case I do `tac_plus -f /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg 2>logfile`, then `logfile` has no content.. @meuh I tried with both `stdbuf -oL -eL tac_plus -f /usr/local/etc/tac_plus.cfg 2>&1 | cat`, but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 2):

If we look at the [sources](http://www.pro-bono-publico.de/projects/unpacked/tac_plus/report.c) we can see function  `report()` which is used to print messages can be configured to write to stderr, or to use `syslog(3)` to get them logged. It also depends on what level of logging you configure.  You can see if the command is doing any writes or syslog calls with eg:

```
strace -e write,connect -o /tmp/out tac_plus ...
```

Look the tmp file for lines like `write(1,...` or other numbers, probably 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr, and 3 or more for `syslog` as it is implemented by opening a socket with `connect()` and writing to it.